# FFMPEG works too slowly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, ffmpeg

i'm currently working on a visual studio c++ project, now i must receive an stream from a Raspberry pi, i'm actually using ffmpeg, the problem is it works to slow in computer side, here is the code i'm using in rapsberry pi:

```
ffserver -f /etc/ffserver.conf & ffmpeg -v 2 -r 20 -s 640x480 -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8090/webcam.ffm
```

and in computer side:

```
void Display(){


//open the video stream and make sure it's opened
if (!cap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
    std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;

}


for (;;) {
    if (!cap.read(frame)) {
        std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
    cv::imshow("Output Window", frame);
    if (cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
}
```

}

Any idea what could be happens? i have a good Ethernet connection (i'm using it to stream)

Comment: keep in mind that it's a raspberry it's not fast per se.

Comment: you are right, but i think this is very very slow!

Comment: What if you try to open the stream with VLC?

Comment: i already tried, but it also works too slow